# How to fetch a string from a list if it contains specified value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a list in Python defined as :

```
data=['multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-modelquality-12as', 'multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-dataquality-2342as']
```

From this list I want to fetch `'multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-modelquality-12as'`, but the problem is that I don't know this exact string, don't know the index.

The only thing I know is that the string could containt `'modelquality'`. So using the string `'modelquality'`, how can I fetch  the `'multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-modelquality-12as'` from data list?

Answer (score -1):

You can filter out all the string that contain `modelquality` like this:

- using [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

```py
data = [
    'multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-modelquality-12as',
    'multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-dataquality-2342as'
]
data = [d for d in data if 'modelquality' in d]
```

- using [filter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter)

```py
data = [
    'multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-modelquality-12as',
    'multirislmtdl-endpoint-name-dataquality-2342as'
]
data = list(filter(lambda d: 'modelquality' in d, data))
```